# Using min/maxscaledenominator rule in GeoServer to filter data from heavy layer served as WMS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet

I have a heavy multiline layer (>1.5GB) saved in a PostGIS database, connected to GeoServer 2.14 and being served as WMS to be displayed in a Leaflet map.

Right now, the layer is shown correctly in the map, but the user experience was at first terrible. I have been trying to improved the performance and so far, I have:

- The same CRS in GeoServer, PostGIS and Leaflet.
- png8 as the image/format in the request.
- The request has the parameter: tiled = true.
- Used GeoWebCache to caché the layer.
- GeoServer is using the production logging.
- GeoServer has "Support on the fly geometry simplification" activated.

This has made that once the layer is loaded, the user can interact with it in a much smoother way than before, but I think this can be improved even more, specially the first time it is loaded.

I have been reading that the rule min/maxscaledenominator can be used to show certain data at different scales. I have only used this rule to style the layer, but never to load (show/hide) certain data.

This is the way I use min/maxscaledenominator:

```
     <Rule>
       <Name>Medium</Name>
       <MinScaleDenominator>180000000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>360000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#009933</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
```

Is it possible to show/hide layer content with this rule? If so, does anyone have an example? I have been unable to find any on the net, although people mention it can be used that way.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what seems to be your problem? do the scale denominators not work?

Comment: Hi Ian, at first I tried following old threads such as this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76093/geoserver-wms-layer-is-very-slow 

As you see, they recommend: "Make sure large datasets are scaled to not render at all zoom levels (this is defined in the layer/WMS sld file)". Here is where I a stuck, because scale denominator works for styling the layer. I am not able to render certain data with it. I will try to post the (not working) tests I have been doing.

Comment: Stating the size of the table in GB doesn't give any sense of the number of features, the number of vertices per feature, and the number of features per map.

Comment: If I run: SELECT sum(ST_NPoints(geom)) The table (layer) has 28485651 points and  SELECT sum(ST_NumGeometries(geom)) results in: 1100122. Does this help?

Comment: If you have just that one rule and scale is not within the defined range 180000000-360000000 nothing should be rendered. Does is not work that way for you? See for example http://geo.ifip.tuwien.ac.at/imak/2009/stack_workshop/doc/sld_basic/scale.html.

Comment: You can find SLD examples with heavily filtered and scale dependent layers from https://github.com/melbsurfer/osm-geoserver-styles/tree/master/sld.

Comment: Oh thanks for the links @user30184 Seem very promising. Will give them a try and let you know.

Comment: Ok, I think I do now understand:

With SLD you can show/hide full layers based on scale. Applying this SLD to different layers, allows to load them depending on scale, and show combinations of layers at different scales.

I thought you could show different features of the layer depending on scale, but as far as I understood, SLD is not meant for this. I will start to read about the "Filter" rule  that has operators such as "equalto".... Thanks for the information and links.